# Indian Spider Identification

Tags: species-identification, entomology, arachnology

Today I saw this curious colorful spider on its web near a [sapota tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pouteria_sapota) in my garden.
I have never seen any spider like this,its around 2cm or a little less.

The most curious part is this part of its exoskeleton which looks like when a moth rests.Like a cape.

[image: top side]

here's the underside and the yellow patterned legs.
[image: bottom side]

But the spider was bothered by my presence and was trying to crawl away,and I took this angled shot:

[image: angled pic]

I live in South India.

So what is this spider ?

Is there any advantage of the wing like part?

*Links to websites with details of the spider are also appreciated.*

Answer (score 3):

That’s maybe an oriental spiny orbweaver (Gasteracantha geminata), according to its appearance and location. You can find many more observations of such spiders on iNaturalist: https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/207992-Gasteracantha-geminata?locale=en-GB

However, I don’t know what advantage there is to the “spines”. They are not the only species. There’s a whole genus of them with at least 70 known species, according to Wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiny_orb-weaver